# KISS or Extrapolate questions?

Tags: discussion

A comment that Michael made in [this question](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/94944/is-there-a-term-for-overlapping-images-due-to-incomplete-film-transport/94945?noredirect=1#comment172929_94945) got me thinking.

The question itself has been answered and was actually hyper-focused on the terminology.

The answer extrapolates out a little and gets into how-to territory. My comment takes that a step further by offering how-to advice for other cameras...and Michael's comment reminds us all that there are other operations still.

Is it the purpose of SE to Keep It Simple (Stupid) and just answer the question that was asked - or is there reason to extrapolate further out, potentially even modifying the original question or linking to other questions?

For example, this terminology question could link to a "How do I perform a Double Exposure" question that then contains an answer giving that answer for various camera models. Should this question not already exist - is it worth it to create it and link it so as to create a network of information?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

KISS.

The question here is if there is a specific term for *partially* overlapping frames on a 35mm camera, thus partially double exposing them.

The correct answer to this is either "no, there is not" or "yes, it's called X".

Adding info about how to do a double exposure on various types of cameras should be covered in a question "how do I achieve a double exposure on an old 35mm camera that lacks a button for it" or whatever.

The OP makes it clear he knows the term double exposure, and knows how to acheive it on a film camera, he's simply asking if there's a term for partially advancing the frames.

Any attempt to change the question, or answer with stuff about how to do it, is way beyond what he's asking.  And probably unlikely, but what if there *is* a name for this technique, with a Flickr group dedicated to it, but the question has meanwhile morphed into a generic double exposure question.

So no, I say we should keep questions and answers focused.  Links to related topics are fine, but I don't think answers should broaden the scope of the question when that information can be better focused on another question.